# Sending props to parent on second render using conponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have Parent component which calls the child component

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.data = this.getData();
  }
  getData(val){
  // this is where the problems come when setting
  // val on the second render
   if(typeof val != "undefined"){
    return val;
   }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Child sendData={this.getLineOffset} onDataLoaded={this.forceUpdate}/>

      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default Home;
```

In the child component I run componentDidMount function because I need to get an offset of a div which is being rendered on the first render. And on the second render it gets the refs value

```
export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        // sending props to the parent
        this.props.sendData(this.refs.el.offsetLeft);
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="el" > </div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that in the parent I only get value from the first render in the parent, because constructor is saving only the first value i return in the getData funcion.

I understand it is not the best practice, but I couldn't find any other ways to get the offset of the rendered content.

I have tried using forceUpdate when the data is loaded but the value is still undefined.

Of course if console log in the getData function It will display but still  not saved in the constructor.

How could i solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get new values by adding a `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in the child component. You then compare the oldProps and the newProps on the second render and update the props to the new one.